# Not Able to Create AWS HTTP API resource "Intergrations" using AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I just want to create integration for HTTP AWS API Gateway for integrate with Private Resource(VPC_Link) using aws cli command.

Below the Sample Command:

```
aws apigatewayv2 create-integration --api-id bcx43qexs5 --integration-type HTTP_PROXY \
    --connection-type VPC_LINK \
    --connection-id sxm2td \
    --timeout-in-millis 6000 \
    --tls-config portal.example.com \
    --integration-method ANY \
    --integration-uri arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-2:123456789123:listener/net/GF-Load-Balancer/2565e667f8797848/c5bb84af7eccdf34
    --payload-format-version 1.0
```

I already tried, getting error

> An error occurred (BadRequestException) when calling the CreateIntegration operation: PayloadFormatVersion is a required parameter for integration
> zsh: command not found: --payload-format-version

What's wrong here?

Comment: did you solve the problem or still need some help?

Answer (score 0):

From your command it looks like your forgot one `\` after `--integration-uri arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-2:123456789123:listener/net/GF-Load-Balancer/2565e667f8797848/c5bb84af7eccdf34`  unless this is on the same line as `--payload-format-version`. However, from your code formatting it doesn't look like it, so please try to run the command as:

```
aws apigatewayv2 create-integration --api-id bcx43qexs5 --integration-type HTTP_PROXY \
    --connection-type VPC_LINK \
    --connection-id sxm2td \
    --timeout-in-millis 6000 \
    --tls-config portal.example.com \
    --integration-method ANY \
    --integration-uri arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-2:123456789123:listener/net/GF-Load-Balancer/2565e667f8797848/c5bb84af7eccdf34 \
    --payload-format-version 1.0
```

If you are running it on a Windows command line, replace `\` with `^`.